# please append a correct root= ... end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount rootfs on unknown block(0,0)

Tags: boot, system-installation

[ubuntu boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APLbv.jpg)

[boot error (end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount rootfs on unknown block(0,0))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnML4.jpg)

I was trying to update and I got to this, not sure what to do

Comment: Can you boot to the older kernel if you go into Advanced Options in GRUB?  There is a chance that during the update, if it is a new kernel, that it didn't build the initramfs correctly and that is why it is not mounting root.